# Eclipse plugin: Path to jar directory for html site

Tags: java, html, image, jar, eclipse-plugin

I'm generating a temporary html site with my Eclipse plugin. As it seems, it is not possible to use the common way as for Java Swing, like so:

```
URL location = getClass().getResource("/img/notifications/pic.png");
InputStream inputStream = location.openStream();
final Image ideaImage = new Image(display, inputStream);
```

I tried using this, but logically I only get `bundleresource://592.fwk513700442:1/img/html/pic.png`.

So currently I'm using the following approach:

```
URL configURL = bc.getBundle().getResource("/img/html/pic.png");
File configFile = new File(FileLocator.toFileURL(configURL).getPath());
location = configFile.toString().substring(0, configFile.toString().length()-7);
// 7 = length of "pic.png" to get the root folder
```

This works, but only for the image for which I enter the name above. It's cumbersome to loop over all the images, I think, so there must be a better solution...

Another solution would be to extract all my JAR contents into a local folder, but that's not really what I want as the user shouldn't be able to easily access all the files.

**EDIT: Clarification**

I do have an exported plugin in jar format. From inside this plugin I open up the user's native browser and open a temporary file. I do this with the following class:

```
package de.stefansurkamp.handlers;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator;
import org.eclipse.equinox.security.storage.StorageException;
import org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException;
import org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.FrameworkUtil;

public class WebsiteGenerator {

    private StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    private ArrayList<Member> achievementList = new ArrayList<Member>();
    private String location;

    public WebsiteGenerator() {
        try {
            // get location information
            BundleContext bc = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(WebsiteGenerator.class).getBundleContext();              
            URL configURL = bc.getBundle().getResource("/img/html/firstCompile.png");
            File configFile = new File(FileLocator.toFileURL(configURL).getPath());
            location = configFile.toString().substring(0, configFile.toString().length()-16);

            // append HTML head
            output.append("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head>");

            // apend HTML body
            output.append(generateHtmlBody());
        }
        catch(IOException e1) {
            System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void createPage() throws IOException, PartInitException {
        File temp = File.createTempFile(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()),".html");
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(temp);
        writer.write(output.toString());
        writer.close();
        PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getBrowserSupport().getExternalBrowser().openURL(temp.toURI().toURL());
        temp.deleteOnExit();
    }

    private String generateHtmlBody() throws IOException {
        try {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(7250);
        stringBuilder.append("<body>");

        [a lot of other appends]

        stringBuilder.append("<img width=\"162\" height=\"162\" src=\"" + location + getAchievementID() + ".png\" alt=\"");
        // getAchievementID returns an "id" which is equal to the picture name i want to insert here.
        stringBuilder.append("</div>");
        stringBuilder.append("</body>");
        stringBuilder.append("</html>");

        return stringBuilder.toString();
        }
        catch(StorageException e) {
            System.out.println("STORAGE EXCEPTION: " + e.getErrorCode());
            return "";
        }
    }    
}
```

Although this is not an SSCCE, I hope it became clear how I manage to create the web site.

The problem here is, that I cannot use a "local URL" (as described above) because the image path root is not inside the plugin, but ouside (in the browser). Is there a solution, how to "find" the path towards inside the jar package towards the image folder?

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to do. Do you just want an SWT image from a resource?

Comment: @greg-449: I edited my initial question and added some code as well as an explanation.